# Infinite loop with updated attribute inside a Backbone Model change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, infinite-loop, backbone-events

I am using Backbone and ReactJS to keep few HTML `div`s (lets call them boxes) stacked inside another `div` (lets call this container). Users can zoom in this container which also zoom in boxes (nothing to do with CSS zoom property). When a zoom event triggered on the container, I calculate total height of the zoomed in boxes and update the container with the new height of the stack. Actual code is but cumbersome, following code mimic exact scenario which leads to infinite loop.

On following code, user changes zoom value on ClickButton model. Based on `zoom` value, I calculate new `j` and update it. I also updated `k` when `j` changes. Now I am in a infinite loop of incrementing `k`'s value. Test this on code by clicking on "Click" button. Variable `k` rushes to 100 (intentionally breaks at 100, else browser will freeze)

My understanding:
It looks like when I update k or whatever inside Backbone model's on change handler, it create another change event. This new event start executing once the previous event ended. However, this new event still return true for the function call `this.hasChanged("j")`, which happened prior to and handled on the previous event.

Current solution:
I am using `{silent : true}` option as an input to Backbone `set` method and successfully able to stop the infinite loop.

I would like another way of doing this without suppressing the on change events since my updating of HTML page relies on change events. My ReactJS app hooked on to the model and it updates the view on model change.

Anyone knows a better solution?

```js
var ClickButton = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      className: "display",
      zoom: 0,
      j: 0,
      k: 0,
      children: [],
    }
  },
  initialize() {
    getElement("zoom").value = this.get("zoom");
    getElement("zoomchanged").value = 0;
    this.on("change", function(e) {
      if (this.hasChanged("j")) {
        getElement("j").value = this.get("zoom");
        if (this.get("k") < 100) {
          // Just added hundred that your browser wont get stuck
          this.set("k", parseInt(this.get("k")) + 1);
          getElement("k").value = parseInt(this.get("k"));
        }
      }
      if (this.hasChanged("zoom")) {
        getElement("zoomchanged").value = parseInt(getElement("zoomchanged").value) + 1;
        console.log(this.get("zoom"));
        getElement("zoom").value = this.get("zoom");
        this.set("j", this.get("zoom"));
      }
    });
  }
});

var clickButton = new ClickButton();

var button = getElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", (function(e) {
  var currentValueOfZoom = clickButton.get("zoom");
  clickButton.set("zoom", currentValueOfZoom + 1);
}).bind(this));

// Helpers
function getElement(className) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 35px;
}

div#holder {
  display: flex;
}

div#holder input {
  margin-right: 23px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
  <label>K: </label><input class="k" type="text"><br>
  <label>J: </label><input class="j" type="text"><br>
  <label>zoom: </label><input class="zoom" type="text"><br>
  <label>Number of times zoom changed: </label><input class="zoomchanged" type="text"><br>
  <div class="display">

  </div>
  <button class="button">
  Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of behavior could be prevented with Backbone's `silent:true` [option](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set). However, as noted in the documentation, a better solution would be to pass a specific flag (such as the `ignore: true` flag I'm passing and checking against in the snippet below).

From the backbone docs:

> Generally speaking, when calling a function that emits an event (model.set, collection.add, and so on...), if you'd like to prevent the event from being triggered, you may pass {silent: true} as an option. Note that this is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea. Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better.

```
this.on("change", function(e, options){
    if(options.ignore !== true && this.hasChanged("zoom")){
        getElement("zoomchanged").value = parseInt(getElement("zoomchanged").value) + 1;
        console.log(this.get("zoom"));
        getElement("zoom").value = this.get("zoom");
        this.set("j", this.get("zoom"), {ignore: true});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue. +1 since I never knew I could pass custom data as options. I always thought options are like instruction for Backbone internals like {silent : true} will suppress on change event.

Answer (score 0):

*While [lucasjackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504561/1218980) provides a working patch specific to your situation, I would like to share the best practices anyway.*

## What's happening?

[`.hasChanged`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-hasChanged) only returns the latest changes made through a `set` and doesn't keep track of any other subsequent changes, *unless they are made in a related triggering event.* Once a `set` is completely done, any subsequent call to `set` will overwrite the [`changed` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed).

Since you're changing `zoom`, `j` and `k` inside a generic `change` event, any subsequent `set` triggers a new `change` event where `hasChanged` always returns true since the `changed` property looks like this:

```
{
    zoom: 1,
    j: 1,
    k: 100,
}
```

## How to solve this infinite loop?

Multiple things can be done to simplify and improve your model. First, **don't play with the DOM inside a Backbone Model.** This is a job for the view, so React in your case.

With that in mind, use [specific attribute change event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) handlers (`change:[attribute]`).

```
var ClickButton = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        zoom: 0,
        j: 0,
        k: 0,
    },
    initialize() {
        this.listenTo(this, {
            'change:zoom': this.onZoomChange,
            'change:j': this.onJChange
        });
    },
    onZoomChange(model, value, options) {
        this.set("j", this.get("zoom"));
    },
    onJChange(model, value, options) {
        this.set("k", parseInt(this.get("k")) + 1);
    }
});
```

---

That being said, I'm not sure a Backbone Model is a good choice to handle a button click. But then again, you haven't shared the React code...